# Nattable - ButtonPainter on cell is going on edit mode on click ,

Tags: nattable

i am trying to follow class Rendereing_a_cell_as_a_button

https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/examples/_102_Configuration/Rendering_cells_as_a_link_and_button.java

from Nattable example to create similar button , i have copied same example code.

Button is showing on the desired column, but on click the style is not getting change of button like clicked and also listener is not getting called, it is going to edit mode and showing the content of cell.

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSHS2.jpg)

[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p49PD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If your table also supports editing you need to ensure that cells in the column that shows buttons should be not editable. This can be done by registering an IEditableRule#NEVER_EDITABLE for that column.

Comment: I have already tried that IEditableRule#NEVER_EDITABLE for that column, but still that was not working , i also have doubt that  a column with NEVER_EDITABLE  will be able to click for ButtonPainter ?

Comment: The ButtonPainter has no relation to editing. So it should work. But by only showing screenshots instead of code, how should anyone help?